# Getting a hyperlink generated in sheet.getRange in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink

I am generating google docs from a google sheets using apps script. The link of the google doc is then returned in the same google sheet. The cells in google sheets are inserted in the template that I am using (e.g. Name, Address, Date, etc). After the template is tailored according to the rows, the url is generated in an additional column.

What I have -> Returning url in one column and the name of the google doc in a second column in 16 and 17 column respectively.

```
doc.saveAndClose();
const url = doc.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(index+1,16).setValue(url)
sheet.getRange(index+1,17).setValue(copy)
//url = url of the new google doc
//copy = name of the new google doc
```

What I want -> To have the hyperlink with `url` named as `copy`.

How can I proceed?

Comment: I am anot sure whether I understand your qeustion correctly. Would you like to rename your document?

Comment: Actually no. Currently the google doc url is returned in one column and google doc name is returned in another column. I want to receive the document name with hyperlink of the google doc url.

Comment: Ok, got you now.

Answer (score 0):

### To insert a hyperlink into spreadsheet programmatically

- Use the method [setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula).
- Apply the formula [=HYPERLINK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en).

Sample:

```js
sheet.getRange(index+1,17).setFormula('=hyperlink("' + url +'","' + copy + '")');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is what i needed. Though I had to break the single quotes `'` and use `+` the plus signs as had to put variables in the setFormula method.

Comment: Sorry, this was a negligence from my part, since I tested with hard coded values, will update the answer now!